# Getting records with month by month, year by year and day by day from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm looking for a fast and easy SQL Query to get records year by year, month by month and day by day.

My database example:

```
ID - DATE        - CatID - VALUE
1  - 2013-08-06  -  32   -  243
2  - 2013-08-16  -  2    -  45
3  - 2013-08-21  -  2    -  1
4  - 2013-08-05  -  32   -  450
5  - 2013-08-05  -  32   -  449
6  - 2013-08-05  -  32   -  11
7  - 2013-08-01  -  2    -  221
8  - 2013-08-02  -  32   -  0
9  - 2013-08-02  -  32   -  0
10 - 2013-08-02  -  32   -  987
...
..
```

I have over 2 millions records on this table.

**First:**

I would like to get CatID = 32 and single/higher record of the day.

Result:

```
1  - 2013-08-06  -  32   -  243
4  - 2013-08-05  -  32   -  450
10 - 2013-08-02  -  32   -  987
```

**Second:**

I would like to get as same but by **MONTH**.

How can I do it with SQL SERVER. Currently Sql Server 2012.

Also using C# 5 and if you want to use, EF 6.

**Down voters, this question became "popular question". Now please explain why down voted?**

Comment: This is a super simple SQL question.  Did you try anything?

Comment: Tried some. For example I don't know how to get from 2014 max values. I have 2 million records at 2014. And I want to get the max valued row from 2014. and same for other years...

Comment: Are you familiar with the `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below assumes that you want more than just the max value for each date/month, but also want to know the `id` of that row, etc, etc.

For daily...

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatID,
                                    Date
                           ORDER BY Value DESC)   AS ordinal_cat_date
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  ordinal_cat_date = 1
  AND catID = 32
```

For monthly...

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatID,
                                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)
                           ORDER BY Value DESC)   AS ordinal_cat_month
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  ordinal_cat_month = 1
  AND catID = 32
```

In both cases the `ROW_NUMBER()` function creates a sequence of numbers `(1,2,3,4,etc)` for each `PARTITION` of `catID, date`, in descending order of `value`.  Whichever row has a value of `1` is the row with the highest value in that partition.

The formula `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)` just rounds the `Date` down to the first day of the month, thereby creating partitions for whole months.

Some other options that bring through multiple rows per day/month if those rows all share the same highest value...

```
SELECT  -- Daily Version
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM yourTable   AS lookup
               WHERE lookup.CatID = yourTable.CatID
                 AND lookup.Value > yourTable.Value
                 AND lookup.Date  = yourTable.Date
             )
  AND CatID = 32
```

```
SELECT  -- Monthly Version
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM yourTable   AS lookup
               WHERE lookup.CatID  = yourTable.CatID
                 AND lookup.Value >  yourTable.Value
                 AND lookup.Date  >= DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, yourTable.Date), 0)
                 AND lookup.Date  <  DATEADD(MONTH, 1+DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, yourTable.Date), 0)
             )
  AND CatID = 32
```

Or possibly...

```
SELECT  -- Daily Version
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    Date,
    CatID,
    MAX(Value)   AS max_value
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    CatID,
    Date
)
  AS lookup
    ON  yourTable.Date  = lookup.Date
    AND yourTable.CatID = lookup.CatID
    AND yourTable.Value = lookup.max_value
WHERE
  yourTable.CatID = 32
```

```
SELECT  -- Monthly Version
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    CatID,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, yourTable.Date), 0)   AS month_start,
    MAX(Value)   AS max_value
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    CatID,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, yourTable.Date), 0)
)
  AS lookup
    ON  yourTable.Date  >= lookup.month_start
    AND yourTable.Date  <  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, lookup.month_start)
    AND yourTable.CatID  = lookup.CatID
    AND yourTable.Value  = lookup.max_value
WHERE
  yourTable.CatID = 32
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering :) When I execute "For daily" got this: http://i.imgur.com/vv5AHAF.png ; I would like to get all days. How can i do it? thanks

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu - That screenshot implies that for `MeterID=3` you only have data for one date.

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu - Two observations.  **`1.`** Your field name is `MeterReadDate` and not `Date`, so the query needs to have `MeterReadDate` in the `PARTITION BY`.  **`2.`** These are not dates, but actually date-times.  If you want it `per date` then you need to use `PARTITION BY MeterID, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, MeterReadDate), 0)` in order to round that field down to the beginning of the day.